# Changing the node value using javascript on xforms:submit event does not reflect into the model instance

Tags: javascript, orbeon, xforms

xforms:submit event is raised before the submission happens and any changes to node values before submission can be achieved.

I have tried doing this, i could see the value is getting changed on the browser, but the saved node still have the old data. Any idea on this.

```
<xforms:submission id="save-instance" ref="instance('form-instance')" 
    action="{instance('temp-instance')/submit-url}" method="post" validate="false" replace="none">

    <xforms:action ev:observer="save-instance" ev:event="xforms-submit">
        <xforms:message level="modal" value="'About to Submit'" />
        <xxforms:script>
            ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue("location-of-dda-id-a", 'Test3');
        </xxforms:script>
    </xforms:action>

    <xforms:action ev:observer="save-instance" ev:event="xforms-submit-done">
        <xforms:message level="modal" ref="instance('metaData')/save-success-msg" />
    </xforms:action>
    <xforms:message ev:event="xforms-submit-error" level="modal" ref="instance('metaData')/save-error-msg" />
</xforms:submission>
```

And the id `location-of-dda-id-a` is the id given for an input field.

Basically, i wanted to replace the special characters that are copied and pasted from MS documents. Below is the Js function that can achieve this.

```
var specialChars = [/\u0011/g, /\u0012/g, /\u0013/g, /\u0014/g, /\u0016/g, /\u2018/g, /\u2019/g, /\u201c/g, /\u201d/g, /\u2026/g, /\u2013/g, /\u2219/g, /\u2022/g,/\u00BF/g];
var specialCharsReplacement = ["", "", "", "", "", "'", "'", "\"", "\"", "...","-","-","-","?"];

function replaceSpecialChars(formName) 
{
    for(i = 0; i < formName.elements.length; i++) 
    {
        if (formName.elements[i].type == 'textarea' || formName.elements[i].type=='text')
        {        
            var commentText = formName.elements[i].value;
            if(commentText != 0) 
            {          
                for(j = 0; j < specialChars.length; j++) 
                {
                    commentText = commentText.replace(specialChars[j], specialCharsReplacement[j]);
                }               
                formName.elements[i].value = commentText;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And the line

```
formName.elements[i].value = commentText;
```

should be replaced with

```
ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue(formName.elements[i].id.split("\$")[0], commentText);
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tricky one: you're correct to say that the `xforms-submit` action runs before the submission is done, but this happens on the server, and the `xxforms:script` runs on the browser, after everything else was executed on the server. So you need to be somewhat careful when using `xxforms:script`.

In this case, you're better off using an `xforms:setvalue` instead of `xxforms:script` to set the value. (In general, it is better to leave `xxforms:script` for things that can't be done in XForms.)

Comment: Hi Avernet, Thanks for your response. Actually the reason why i am using the javascript here is to replace the all the text and textarea field values having junk characters with acceptable values. Example: Micro – soft Junk’s character‘s “Note it down” If you see these characters are not allowed in Orbeon Forms, hence i have to convert them into like these ..  Micro - soft Junk's character's "Note it down"

Comment: @KaipaMSarma I am not sure to understand what your JavaScript code does based on this example. Would you be able to paste that JavaScript code here?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! In XForms, first, you would need to iterate over the nodes for which you want to do the replacement. Say you want to do this for all the leaf elements: `<xf:action xxf:iterate="//*">`. Then, inside the iteration you'll need a number of `<xf:setvalue ref="." value="replace('a', 'b')"/>`.

Comment: All the `<xf:setvalue>` will be quite verbose, but this is the simplest solution to describe. You could avoid this by declaring the list characters to replace and their replacements in two sequences, and iterating over those, in inner loop (`xxf:iterate`) as you did in JavaScript, but it is harder to describe :).